# Java: how to remove specific object when button clicked

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I'm trying to remove an object by clicking it's button, but what happens is when I click the button inside the panel it removes the last created panel.

Question is how will I remove the specific panel that I want?

Here's my code:

```
public class TimerPractice extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JPanel main=new JPanel();
    JPanel gui=new JPanel();
    JButton btnadd=new JButton("Add Timer");
    JPanel order=new JPanel();

    public TimerPractice()
    {

        main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gui.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        main.add(btnadd, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        main.add(gui,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(main);
        btnadd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                //addPanel();
                //System.out.print(x);
                addPanel();
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });

        main.add(gui);
    }


    public void addPanel()
    {
        Border blackline=BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        order=new JPanel();
        order.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,300));
        order.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        TitledBorder title=BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(blackline);
        title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.LEFT);
        order.setBorder(title);
        addBtn();
        gui.add(order);
    }

    public void addBtn()
    {
        JButton remove=new JButton("Remove");
        order.add(remove, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                gui.remove(order);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TimerPractice p=new TimerPractice();
        p.setSize(1000,800);
        p.setVisible(true);
        p.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are making new `order` each time you call `addPanel()`. Keep a track of all the new panels created using ADTs like [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: if I'm not going to make a new `order` then it will just overwrite the panel I've created

Comment: Think about isolating your components into self contained/managed entities, this way, you won't need to care...

Comment: @MadProgrammer how sorry I don't know much...

Comment: Create a custom class which extends from `JPanel`, which encapsulates the responsibilities of your current `order` pane.  Then it becomes much simpler to manage and maintain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you add a new `order` panel, you are reassigning the reference to `order` to point to the last created `JPanel`, this means that when you say `remove(order)`, it only knows how to remove the last panel you created...

Long answer, separate each `order` panel into it's own, self contained and managed entity, this way you won't run into the reference issues you are having right now...

Short answer, extract the reference from the `ActionEvent`...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source instanceof Component) {
        Component comp = (Component)source;
        gui.remove(comp.getParent());
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

You could use an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to generate a self contained unit of work, which you would pass a reference of the current instance of `order`, this would allow the `Action` to maintain it's own reference separate from the `TimerPractice` class

Comment: when I click the remove button it does nothing... is there anything else I need to edit?

Comment: Hehehe, typed to fast.  It should the parent of the source that triggered the action event, see updates

Comment: amazing! ((: ahahaha how do you know all this ((: I envy you! :D

Comment: I've been coding in Java and Swing since 1999, lots and lots of hacking and trying things ... oh and not having a life helps ;)