# Enabling a Button by checking all the required checkbox

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcheckbox

I'm trying to create a program where a `JButton` will only be enabled if all the `JCheckBoxes` are Checked, But I'm having problem with enabling the specific `JButton` because once I checked all the `JCheckBoxes` the only `JButton` being enabled is the last created

Here's my code:

```
public class Practice extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JPanel main=new JPanel();
    JPanel gui=new JPanel();
    JButton btnadd=new JButton("Add Timer");
    JPanel order=new JPanel();
    JPanel chkPanel=new JPanel();
    JButton remove=new JButton("Remove");

    public Practice()
    {

        main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gui.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        main.add(btnadd, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        main.add(gui,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(main);
        btnadd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            int ctr=0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                ctr+=1;
                //addPanel();
                //System.out.print(x);
                addPanel(ctr);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });

        main.add(gui);
    }


    public void addPanel(int ctr)
    {
        Border blackline=BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        order=new JPanel();
        order.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,300));
        order.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        TitledBorder title=BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(blackline);
        title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.LEFT);
        order.setBorder(title);
        addCheckPanel(ctr);
        addBtn();
        gui.add(order);
    }

    public void addCheckPanel(int ctr)
    {
        chkPanel=new JPanel();
        chkPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(chkPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
            addCheck(ctr);
        order.add(chkPanel);
    }
    int y;
    public void addCheck(int ctr)
    {
        JCheckBox check=new JCheckBox("Check Me");
        chkPanel.add(check);
        y=ctr;
        check.addActionListener(listener);

    public void addBtn()
    {
        remove=new JButton("Remove");
        order.add(remove, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        remove.setEnabled(false);
        remove.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TimerPractice p=new TimerPractice();
        p.setSize(1000,800);
        p.setVisible(true);
        p.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    ActionListener listener=new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
             Object source = e.getSource();
             if (source instanceof Component) 
             {
                Component comp = (Component)source;
                gui.remove(comp.getParent());
                revalidate();
                repaint();
             }
         }
    };


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't we already fix this problem?  Isolate your functionality in single units of work, this is known as encapsulation...it's why you use an OO language in the first place and I'm sure I've said this at least 3 times...

Comment: sorry... I don't understand what you mean by isolating my functions

Comment: This is the exact same issue you faced in [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028396/java-how-to-remove-specific-object-when-button-clicked) cause by the same problem...

Comment: *"Isolate your functionality"* - Create a single, custom component, which performs all the required actions you need it to.  Create new instances of this class and then add those to your main UI.  The custom components become self contained units of work, which know what they need to do in order to achieve their responsibilities...

Comment: sorry... I really don't know how to program that good... I'm still trying to fix it

Comment: Well, you're going to continue having these issues until you do, as they are the same issues, just in different places within your code, you need to change tactic in order to fix them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to isolate and separate your units of work.  For example, your `order` panel has controls and functionality, which would be better separated into it's own class, where it can maintain it's own state independently of other instances of itself, for example...

You could pull much of the code of your main class and create a separate class, for example `OrderPane`...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class OrderPane extends JPanel {

    private JPanel chkPanel;
    private int selectedCount = 0;
    private int checkCount = 0;

    private JButton removeButton;

    public OrderPane(int checkCount) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(blackline);
        title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.LEFT);
        setBorder(title);

        this.checkCount = checkCount;

        addCheckPanel();
        addBtn();

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 300);
    }

    public void addCheckPanel() {
        chkPanel = new JPanel();
        chkPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(chkPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for (int i = 0; i < checkCount; i++) {
            addCheck();
        }
        add(chkPanel);
    }

    public void addCheck() {
        JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("Check Me");
        chkPanel.add(check);
        check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
                if (cb.isSelected()) {
                    selectedCount++;
                } else {
                    selectedCount--;
                }
                if (selectedCount == checkCount) {
                    removeButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void addBtn() {
        removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
        add(removeButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        removeButton.setEnabled(false);
        removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Object source = e.getSource();
                if (source instanceof Component) {
                    Component comp = (Component) source;
                    Component myParent = comp.getParent();
                    Container yourParent = myParent.getParent();
                    yourParent.remove(myParent);
                    yourParent.revalidate();
                    yourParent.repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

You would, when needed, create a new instance of this class and add it to you UI as required, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Practice extends JFrame {

    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    JPanel gui = new JPanel();
    JButton btnadd = new JButton("Add Timer");

    public Practice() {

        main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gui.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        main.add(btnadd, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        main.add(gui, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(main);

        final Random rnd = new Random();
        btnadd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                OrderPane orderPane = new OrderPane(rnd.nextInt(10));
                gui.add(orderPane);
                gui.revalidate();
                gui.repaint();
            }
        });

        main.add(gui);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                Practice p = new Practice();
                p.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                p.setSize(800, 600);
                p.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                p.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You might find some of the information from [Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) and [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) of use and no offense, I would understand these topics before tackling something as complex as a UI ;)

#### Side Notes

Normally, I would pass some kind of "controller" `interface` to the `OrderPane`, which would provide the functionality for removing the component from the main UI and other functionality that the `OrderPane` might need in order to provide feedback.

Some of this feedback could be provided via a observer/listener pattern, such as when the timer times out, it would be better to provide some kind event back to registered listeners then perhaps calling a method on the "controller" - IMHO

...but lets deal with one concept at a time...

Comment: This is very important concept, take the time to understand it and use it to your advantage ;)